# How to keep track of depth in breadth first search?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm

I have a tree as input to the breadth first search and I want to know as the algorithm progresses at which level it is?

```python
# Breadth First Search Implementation
graph = { 
    'A':['B','C','D'],
    'B':['A'],
    'C':['A','E','F'],
    'D':['A','G','H'],
    'E':['C'],
    'F':['C'],
    'G':['D'],
    'H':['D']
    }


def breadth_first_search(graph,source):
    """
    This function is the Implementation of the breadth_first_search program
    """
    # Mark each node as not visited
    mark = {}
    for item in graph.keys():
        mark[item] = 0

    queue, output = [],[]

    # Initialize an empty queue with the source node and mark it as explored
    queue.append(source)
    mark[source] = 1
    output.append(source)

    # while queue is not empty
    while queue:
        # remove the first element of the queue and call it vertex
        vertex = queue[0]
        queue.pop(0)
        # for each edge from the vertex do the following
        for vrtx in graph[vertex]:
            # If the vertex is unexplored
            if mark[vrtx] == 0:
                queue.append(vrtx)  # mark it as explored
                mark[vrtx] = 1      # and append it to the queue
                output.append(vrtx) # fill the output vector
    return output

print breadth_first_search(graph, 'A')
```

It takes tree as an input graph, what I want is, that at each iteration it should print out the current level which is being processed.

Comment: Are you making your own BFS implementation? If yes, its just a depthCounter that you have to use and maintain. Or are you using any off the shelf algorithm??

Comment: I have added the code, no off the shelf algorithm, just a regular breadth first search implementation.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You don't need to use extra queue or do any complicated calculation to achieve what you want to do. This idea is very simple.

This does not use any extra space other than queue used for BFS.

The idea I am going to use is to add `null` at the end of each level. So the number of nulls you encountered +1 is the depth you are at. (of course after termination it is just `level`).

```
     int level = 0;
     Queue <Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
     queue.add(root);
     queue.add(null);
     while(!queue.isEmpty()){
          Node temp = queue.poll();
          if(temp == null){
              level++;
              queue.add(null);
              if(queue.peek() == null) break;// You are encountering two consecutive `nulls` means, you visited all the nodes.
              else continue;
          }
          if(temp.right != null)
              queue.add(temp.right);
          if(temp.left != null)
              queue.add(temp.left);
     }
```

Answer (score 114):

Actually, we don't need an extra queue to store the info on the current depth, nor do we need to add `null` to tell whether it's the end of current level. We just need to know how many nodes the current level contains, then we can deal with all the nodes in the same level, and increase the level by 1 after we are done processing all the nodes on the current level.

```
int level = 0;
Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add(root);
while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    int level_size = queue.size();
    while (level_size-- != 0) {
        Node temp = queue.poll();
        if (temp.right != null) queue.add(temp.right);
        if (temp.left != null) queue.add(temp.left);
    }    
    level++;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Maintain a queue storing the depth of the corresponding node in BFS queue. Sample code for your information:

```
queue bfsQueue, depthQueue;
bfsQueue.push(firstNode);
depthQueue.push(0);
while (!bfsQueue.empty()) {
    f = bfsQueue.front();
    depth = depthQueue.front();
    bfsQueue.pop(), depthQueue.pop();
    for (every node adjacent to f) {
        bfsQueue.push(node), depthQueue.push(depth+1);
    } 
}
```

This method is simple and naive, for O(1) extra space you may need the answer post by @stolen_leaves.

Answer (score 5):

Try having a look at this post. It keeps track of the depth using the variable `currentDepth`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923440/3114945

For your implementation, keep track of the left most node and a variable for the depth. Whenever the left most node is popped from the queue, you know you hit a new level and you increment the depth.

So, your root is the `leftMostNode` at level 0. Then the left most child is the `leftMostNode`. As soon as you hit it, it becomes level 1. The left most child of this node is the next `leftMostNode` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

With this Python code you can maintain the depth of each node from the root by increasing the depth only after you encounter a node of new depth in the queue.

```py
    queue = deque()
    marked = set()
    marked.add(root)
    queue.append((root,0))

    depth = 0
    while queue:
        r,d = queue.popleft()
        if d > depth: # increase depth only when you encounter the first node in the next depth               
            depth += 1
        for node in edges[r]:
            if node not in marked:
                marked.add(node)
                queue.append((node,depth+1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a variable `cnt` and initialize it to the size of the queue `cnt=queue.size()`, Now decrement `cnt` each time you do a pop. When `cnt` gets to 0, increase the depth of your BFS and then set `cnt=queue.size()` again.

Answer (score 2):

If your tree is perfectly ballanced (i.e. each node has the same number of children) there's actually a simple, elegant solution here with O(1) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.  The main usecase where I find this helpful is in traversing a binary tree, though it's trivially adaptable to other tree sizes.

The key thing to realize here is that each level of a binary tree contains exactly double the quantity of nodes compared to the previous level.  This allows us to calculate the total number of nodes in any tree given the tree's depth.  For instance, consider the following tree:

[image]

This tree has a depth of 3 and 7 total nodes.  We don't need to count the number of nodes to figure this out though.  We can compute this in O(1) time with the formaula: 2^d - 1 = N, where `d` is the depth and `N` is the total number of nodes.  (In a ternary tree this is 3^d - 1 = N, and in a tree where each node has K children this is K^d - 1 = N).  So in this case, 2^3 - 1 = 7.

To keep track of depth while conducting a breadth first search, **we simply need to reverse this calculation**.  Whereas the above formula allows us to solve for `N` given `d`, we actually want to solve for `d` given `N`. For instance, say we're evaluating the 5th node.  To figure out what depth the 5th node is on, we take the following equation: 2^d - 1 = 5, and then **simply solve for `d`**, which is basic algebra:

[image]

If `d` turns out to be anything other than a whole number, just round up (the last node in a row is always a whole number).  With that all in mind, I propose the following algorithm to identify the depth of any given node in a binary tree during breadth first traversal:

1. Let the variable `visited` equal 0.
2. Each time a node is visited, increment `visited` by 1.
3. Each time `visited` is incremented, calculate the node's depth as `depth = round_up(log2(visited + 1))`

You can also use a hash table to map each node to its depth level, though this does increase the space complexity to O(n).  Here's a PHP implementation of this algorithm:

```
<?php
$tree = [
    ['A', [1,2]],
    ['B', [3,4]],
    ['C', [5,6]],
    ['D', [7,8]],
    ['E', [9,10]],
    ['F', [11,12]],
    ['G', [13,14]],
    ['H', []],
    ['I', []],
    ['J', []],
    ['K', []],
    ['L', []],
    ['M', []],
    ['N', []],
    ['O', []],
];

function bfs($tree) {
    $queue = new SplQueue();
    $queue->enqueue($tree[0]);
    $visited = 0;
    $depth = 0;
    $result = [];

    while ($queue->count()) {

        $visited++;
        $node = $queue->dequeue();
        $depth = ceil(log($visited+1, 2));
        $result[$depth][] = $node[0];


        if (!empty($node[1])) {
            foreach ($node[1] as $child) {
                $queue->enqueue($tree[$child]);
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
}

bfs($tree);
```

Which prints:

```
    Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => A
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => B
                [1] => C
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => D
                [1] => E
                [2] => F
                [3] => G
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => H
                [1] => I
                [2] => J
                [3] => K
                [4] => L
                [5] => M
                [6] => N
                [7] => O
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java it would be something like this.
The idea is to look at the parent to decide the depth.

```
//Maintain depth for every node based on its parent's depth
Map<Character,Integer> depthMap=new HashMap<>();    

queue.add('A');
depthMap.add('A',0); //this is where you start your search

while(!queue.isEmpty())
{
   Character parent=queue.remove();
   List<Character> children=adjList.get(parent);
   for(Character child :children)
   {
      if (child.isVisited() == false) {
           child.visit(parent);
           depthMap.add(child,depthMap.get(parent)+1);//parent's depth + 1
         }

   }

}
```

Comment: this will result in endless loop . you need  to check if child already visited                                                                                                  
        for(String c:children)
     {
        if(!depthMap.containsKey(c)){
      depthMap.put(c,depthMap.get(parent)+1);//parent's depth + 1
        queue.add(c);
        }
     }

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to keep track of the level (distance from start) of each node when exploring the graph.

Example in Python:

```
from collections import deque

def bfs(graph, start):
    queue = deque([start])
    levels = {start: 0}
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.popleft()
        for neighbour in graph[vertex]:
            if neighbour in levels:
                continue
            queue.append(neighbour)
            levels[neighbour] = levels[vertex] + 1
    return levels
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple and easy to read code in python.

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def dfs(self, root):
        assert root is not None
        queue = [root]
        level = 0
        while queue:
            print(level, [n.val for n in queue if n is not None])
            mark = len(queue)
            for i in range(mark):
                n = queue[i]
                if n.left is not None:
                    queue.append(n.left)
                if n.right is not None:
                    queue.append(n.right)
            queue = queue[mark:]
            level += 1
```

Usage,

```
# [3,9,20,null,null,15,7]
n3 = TreeNode(3)
n9 = TreeNode(9)
n20 = TreeNode(20)
n15 = TreeNode(15)
n7 = TreeNode(7)
n3.left = n9
n3.right = n20
n20.left = n15
n20.right = n7
DFS().dfs(n3)
```

Result

```
0 [3]
1 [9, 20]
2 [15, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this method posted so far, so here's a simple one:

You can "attach" the level to the node.  For e.g., in case of a tree, instead of the typical `queue<TreeNode*>`, use a `queue<pair<TreeNode*,int>>` and then push the pairs of `{node,level}`s into it.  The `root` would be pushed in as, `q.push({root,0})`, its children as `q.push({root->left,1})`, `q.push({root->right,1})` and so on...

We don't need to modify the input, append `null`s or even (asymptotically speaking) use any extra space just to track the levels.