# How to keep track of BFS depth in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I want to do BFS on a 2D array, and each of the cell can be represented as `pair<int,int>`. I use `queue<pair<int,int>>` to keep track of cells at each level, but I find no clever way to keep track of the depth. (I don't want to define another struct to record the depth at each level)

[How to keep track of depth in breadth first search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247634/how-to-keep-track-of-depth-in-breadth-first-search)
Here is a solution in Java. Each level is ended with `null`, and we increment the depth once we see `null`.

I am wondering if there's a similar elegant solution in C++. For now, I can think of the following ways:

1) count the number of cells(`push()`) at each level, and decrement the count after each `pop()`. Once `count == 0`, increase the depth.

2) use two `queue` and replace the old one with the new one at the end of each level. Increase the depth at the end of each iteration.

3) maybe stores a pointer to `pair<int,int>` in the queue and use `NULL` to separate levels?

Comment: You'd just use a "marker value". Alternatively, you could use a `std::optional<std::pair<int, int>>` (assuming something like C++17 `std::optional` is available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) can work, but it's better/easier to set count=queue.size(), and decrement it each time you pop.  When it gets to 0, increase the depth and set count=queue.size() again.

(2) works fine.  Use std::swap to switch queues. This is what I usually do, because I like the outer `for(int depth=0; !newnodes.empty(); ++depth)`  you can also use vectors instead of real queues, because you're not pushing and popping on the same object.  The 2nd level loop is just an iteration through a vector.

(3) works, but it's quite wasteful.  Other kinds of marker values can work, but I think the (1) above is better than this in all cases.

In cases where you prefer to use a std::deque instead of two vectors, I like to write it like this:

```
queue.push_back(root);
for (int depth=0; !queue.empty(); ++depth)
{
    for (size_t remaining=queue.size(); remaining>0; --remaining)
    {
        auto item = queue.pop_front();
        //.... queue.push_back(...), etc.
    }
}
```

... which is pretty much like my (1) above, but I get my nice depth loop and by writing the loop condition on `remaining`, we can avoid any other inner loop checks to `queue.empty()`

Comment: Clean and simple solution! 

Answer (score 0):

A solution similar in spirit to inserting a null into the queue is to just insert a sentinel value that can't possibly occur as a cell.  E.g. `pair<numeric_limits<int>::max(), 0>`